# Transferring data between computers on the same network

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, network-shares

Why transfer rate is much higher when transferring to remote PC with copy and paste via Remote Desktop application than when you access to PC on network and copy files to the folder it shares and allows read/write?

Comment: Probably depends what you are copying. Remote Desktop might use compression to transfer things. What are you transferring?

Comment: Zip package mostly

Comment: I think MS just simply has not (at least yet) optimized RDP "copy and paste" to work efficiently and per the way they have coded it to work, it's just slower than other methods that are more optimized to handle file transfers. AFAIK RDP is a MS proprietary protocol so without seeing the code and analyzing it, they would have to accurately answer why it is slow slow in copying files versus other method of file transfers to the same machines. You might play with their RDP file redirection to see if it's optimized more for  file transfers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol